# Views: relationship between tables in two different databases

Tags: views, database

- I've a View that shows data from an external database
- I want to show also data of another table (from the default drupal db) that has a logical relation (like  a foreign key).
- The databases are on the same MySQL server.

It's possible?

Comment: Does the DBMS you're using allow such a join? Or are the databases on the same server?

Comment: I'm using MySQL on the same server and I know that is possible...

Comment: Maybe [this](https://www.drupal.org/node/1530442) is what you're looking for?

Comment: I've not tested that solution, it also seems to have some problem,  but I've resolved with the use of MySQL Views, like explained [here](https://www.drupal.org/node/37075).